# prevent tensorflow device on multiple gpu c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm using a dynamically linked tensorflow library to run a neural network on a c++ code.

```
2018-06-07 19:03:10.578031: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9168 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 
2018-06-07 19:03:10.615271: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 9822 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:17:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   54C    P2   106W / 250W |  10734MiB / 11172MiB |     33%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  1%   54C    P2    65W / 250W |  10655MiB / 11171MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     22230      C   ./demo                                     10723MiB |
|    1      1264      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           309MiB |
|    1      3230      G   compiz                                       235MiB |
|    1     22230      C   ./demo                                     10095MiB |
|    1     25625      G   unity-control-center                           3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The code

```
tf::Session* session_ptr;
auto options = tf::SessionOptions();
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list("0");
auto status = NewSession(tf::SessionOptions(), &session_ptr);
session.reset(tensorflow::NewSession(options));
```

doesn't seem to prevent tensorflow from setting up devices in all of the gpus.

I know you can use the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable, but I need to do this on runtime. I also need to run several instances of this program probably on the same gpu (4 probably)

Is there any way to do this?

I also tried using

```
tf::GraphDef graph_def;
auto status1 = ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(), tf_model, &graph_def);
tensorflow::graph::SetDefaultDevice("0",&graph_def);
```

also allocates memory to both gpu...